# Why does Build & Reload recompile all C++ files even when these are unchanged?

Tags: rstudio, rcpp, roxygen2

I am using RStudio on two machines, with identical configurations, and even the same .Rproj file (from Dropbox).

From the [RStudio webpage](https://support.rstudio.com/hc/en-us/articles/200486088-Using-Rcpp-with-RStudio):

> Incremental Rebuilds
>
> By default RStudio performs incremental rebuilds of packages. C++ files are only recompiled when they change or any header files change. This provides fast turnaround for incremental development.

On one machine, if I modify a simple .R file, or *even if I modify no files at all*, and choose **Build & Reload**, then the C++ does not recompile.

On the other, however, I get:

**With no files changed:**

```
==> devtools::document(roclets=c('rd', 'collate', 'namespace', 'vignette'))

Updating quanteda documentation
Loading quanteda
'/Library/Frameworks/R.framework/Resources/bin/R' CMD INSTALL '/Users/kbenoit/Dropbox (Personal)/GitHub/quanteda' --library='/var/folders/46/zfn6gwj15d3_n6dhyy1cvwc00000gp/T//RtmpowXjeu/devtools_install_cd475c156859' --no-R --no-data --no-help --no-demo --no-inst --no-docs --no-exec --no-multiarch --no-test-load --preclean
Re-compiling quanteda
clang++ -std=c++11 -I/Library/Frameworks/R.framework/Resources/include -DNDEBUG -I. -I/usr/local/include -I/usr/local/include/freetype2 -I/opt/X11/include -I"/Library/Frameworks/R.framework/Versions/3.3/Resources/library/Rcpp/include" -I"/Library/Frameworks/R.framework/Versions/3.3/Resources/library/RcppParallel/include" -I"/Library/Frameworks/R.framework/Versions/3.3/Resources/library/RcppArmadillo/include"   -fPIC  -Wall -mtune=core2 -g -O2 -c RcppExports.cpp -o RcppExports.o
```

etc

**With one .R file changed:**
(which is a data documentation R file with no actual functions)

```
==> Rcpp::compileAttributes()

* Updated src/RcppExports.cpp
* Updated R/RcppExports.R

==> devtools::document(roclets=c('rd', 'collate', 'namespace', 'vignette'))

Updating quanteda documentation
Loading quanteda
'/Library/Frameworks/R.framework/Resources/bin/R' CMD INSTALL '/Users/kbenoit/Dropbox (Personal)/GitHub/quanteda' --library='/var/folders/46/zfn6gwj15d3_n6dhyy1cvwc00000gp/T//RtmpLaNxr4/devtools_install_cdef692abc82' --no-R --no-data --no-help --no-demo --no-inst --no-docs --no-exec --no-multiarch --no-test-load --preclean
Re-compiling quanteda
```

**The question:** How can I get the second machine to do only incremental builds when necessary, which is the supposed default behaviour?

**UPDATE**:

1. I have verified that this is not due to Dropbox, after cloning to a non-Dropbox local repository and building on both machines.
2. The problem does not go away even after using `ccache` in `Makevars` as @DirkEddelbuettel suggests (although this is a great idea for other reasons so I am now using it).
3. The problem *does* go away if I uncheck *Build and Reload* from the *Roxygen Options* box from the Build Tools pane of the Project Options:

[image: Roxygen options]

Comment: Good update.  I had been bitten by this before (but mentioned my workaround).  I tend to set that 'Build & Reload' flag too, particularly for packages where I do use roxygen2 documentation.  I never let roxygen touch DESCRIPTION, NAMESPACE, ... or any of that.  None of that explains the build issue.  Maybe it is roxygen messing with timestamps?

Answer (score 5, accepted):

Fair question.  Quick and somewhat related take, with some caveat:

- I prefer to ignore / avoid devtools as I find that it obfuscates.
- But what follows below would apply to it too.
- The key command(s) here are `R CMD INSTALL` and its friends (ie `R CMD SHLIB` etc)
- AFAIK these simply do NOT have the logic of `make` to not rebuild unless required
- *plus* we are encouraged to run `cleanup` and remove existing artifacts
- and having been bitten in the past, I prefer rebuilds after cleaning

all of which leads to full(er) rebuilds.

*But don't despair*:  The single best trick is to ... avoid this by using

```
 CC=ccache gcc
 CXX=ccache g++
```

and so on, idem for `clang` under OS X.  Just trust the **awesome** [ccache](https://ccache.samba.org/) frontend and your rebuilds (of unchanged code) will be lightning fast.  I have been doing this for many, many years on my work and home machines.

Now there is a related subquestion here:  when/how does RStudio run `compileAttributes()` for us?  I am not sure.  I probably relies (like `make`) on time stamps, and there can be issues with networked drives and shares.  If in doubt I do this locally on the command-line via a littler helper script.

*Edit:* As a convenience, below is what I have in a local dotfile repo.  I allows to set a version for gcc et al which is sometimes needed during compiler transitions. When empty (as right now) it does not harm and we just get `g++` etc.

```
#VER=-4.9
VER=
CCACHE=ccache
CC=$(CCACHE) gcc$(VER)
CXX=$(CCACHE) g++$(VER)
CXX1X=$(CCACHE) g++$(VER)

SHLIB_CXXLD=g++$(VER)

FC=ccache gfortran
F77=ccache gfortran
```

Comment: Hi @Dirk, do we need to keep the above definitions in ```Makevars``` in ```src``` directory?

Comment: One generally puts those into the `~/.R/Makevars` file in the `.R/` subdirectory of a user's own `$HOME` directory.